# Bootstrap 3 daterangepicker not taking 100% width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using custom datepicker (https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) inside my form (http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/a3NV4/22/)

I would like that daterangepicker to take 100% width like all other form elements, but can't get that to work.

My only workaround was to use datepicker css for bootstrap 2. I should use these rules:

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css');
```

but instead I'm using (there is missing `3` at end of second line):

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css');
```

this is what I get when I use bootstrap 3 css:
[image]

also on small screen inputs in picker don't have equal width:

[image]

I would like to switch entirely to bootstrap 3, but this tiny but is stopping me from doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was datepicker custom `.input-group-addon` css.

```
.input-daterange .input-group-addon {
    width: auto; /*remove this line*/
    min-width: 16px;
    padding: 4px 5px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border: solid #cccccc;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
}
```

after removing `width: auto` both bugs were fixed, please see: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/a3NV4/24/

Comment: You may want to set this to the answer to make sure it always appears at the top and anyone with similar issues finds the correct solution quickly.

Comment: @RobQuincey I must wait 2 days to mark this as correct answer, but I'll remember to mark it green :)

Comment: It seems you forgot after all ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could add the `col-xs-12` class to your `input-group`. This will force the group to always be as wide as it's parent container.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Dates range</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="input-daterange" id="datepicker">
             <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                 <input type="text" class="input-small form-control" name="start" />
                 <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
                 <input type="text" class="input-small form-control" name="end" />
             </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3NV4/23/)

Comment: Thanks for such fast answer :) This solved full-width problem, but what about not equal width of inputs?

Comment: On mine the 'to' and 'from' fields appear to be the same width. I even checked Firebugs Box Model viewer and confirmed they always had the same dimensions, all the way up and down the range. Are you getting the problem on a specific browser?

Comment: I've checked right now on IE11 and works fine, but I get this on Chrome (v 36.0.1985.125 m Win8.1), this looks as shown on second screen in my question, could You check that on same browser?

Comment: Yeah I see it as well, but in order to really notice it I have to squige the screen to such small proportions that the actual datepicker that appears doesn't even fit in the window. I doubt your users would ever get to that point. I can't see any quick fix for that, but maybe someone else can.

Comment: I fixed both issues, if not Your help I wouldn't get that, thanks for help and direction!

Comment: Ahh good, I didn't look into the actual CSS as I don't tend to like messing with libraries CSS just in case it has other unintended consequences, but sometimes it's necessary, and it seems to have worked for you.